# How to save image in MYSQL database without post method?

Tags: php

I want to save gif type image in mySQL database without post method.

```
<form action="add_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

I want to upload file by php code only. for example:

```
// Gather all required data
        $name = $File_Name;
        $mime = $File_Type;
        $data = $File_Data;
        $size = $File_Size;

        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO `file` (
                `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
            )
            VALUES (
                '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
            )";
```

I have more then 21,0000 image in my local. I want to save image in loop.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to loop through a folder(s) of images, and insert each into a table contained in a database?

Comment: As it stands your question is too vague to answer.  Why don't you want to use POST?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why? MySQL databases are not meant to store files! That's why **file** system is for!

Comment: Please don't store the image in the database - it's really bad practice

Comment: I would suggest storing image path references in the database, not the images themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the files using FTP, then write a little PHP script that you run only once
that loops through the folder and adds the images to the database.

Make sure to remove the php file after it is done, so that you don't run it again accidentally ;)